# Remove element method doesnt work in Golang

Tags: go, slice

I have a simple code for removing element from slice:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    values := []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
    valuesResult := removeElementByIndex(values2, 0)
    fmt.Printf("%v - %v\n", values, valuesResult)
}

func removeElementByIndex[T interface{}](a []T, i int) []T {
    return append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
}
```

but output is

```
[2 3 4 5 5] - [2 3 4 5]
```

For some reason `values` are changing, but i didnt change it in my method (i guess). Please help me to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did change the original slice. `append` operation uses the original slice if the result of the append operation fits into the capacity of the slice.

If you need the original slice unchanged:

```
func removeElementByIndex[T interface{}](a []T, i int) []T {
    result := make([]T, len(a)-1)
    copy(result,a[:i])
    copy(result[i:],a[i+1:])
    return result
}
```

Comment: `You should add code for bounds checking.`
I'm not sure that you should check that i is in range.  What do you do in that case? Panic?  But the code as it is will panic. (Good answer BTW)

Comment: Good point. Maybe it is ok as is.